# computing complexity of an algorithm (switching element between arrays)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have a very complex function that is called a lot of time. I need to compute the complexity of this algorithm. Given 2 arrays `c` and `r`of len `k` and `l-k` I need to understand how many times complexity increase as a function of `l`and `k`.

We can assume that the called function has complexity `COMP`

```
c = [1,2,3]
r = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]


history = {frozenset(c)}


def switch(c, r, complexity = 0):

    changes = False
    for i in range(len(c)):
        for j in range(len(r)):
            old_c = c.copy()
            old_r = r.copy()
            c[i], r[j] = r[j], c[i]
            if frozenset(c) in history:
                c = old_c
                r = old_r
            else:
                changes = True
                history.add(frozenset(c))
                complexity += 1 # call a very expensive function so complexity + 1
    return changes, complexity


complexity = 0
changes = True
while changes :
    changes, complexity = switch(c,r, complexity)
```

EDIT:
Note that the algorithm does not generate all the combinations but a subset of them

```
print('complexity = ', complexity)
# 130            


from itertools import combinations
combs = set(combinations(range(len(r)+len(c)), 3))
print('total number of combinations=', len(combs))
#220
```

Comment: When is this homework assignment due?

Comment: It is not an homework I need it for a research paper :)

Comment: if you want some kind of heuristic approach: call the function with varying l and k, record their execution time. finally, use function approximation from the acquired data. tadaaa~~~you get an almost correct function (but I doubt it will be accepted)

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: I would like a mathematical result something like `O(k^2)` that is why I am avoiding the numerical results. I am not using combinations because I think that this approach does not use all the possible combinations but only a smaller subsets

Comment: Why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: @Donbeo Do you want to know the complexity or do you really need an automatic complexity detection? Latter without constraints is impossible.

Comment: @deviantfan I would like an upper bound of the complexity. I know that for sure the complexity is lower than the ones required to compute all the possible combinations. I am wondering if there is a tighter bound.